# Facing org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found Exception

Tags: file-upload, filenotfoundexception

while using sendkeys to upload a file in java selenium it is throwing an error
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found : C:\Users\VK32827\Updated RCL Project\research-gtf-RLC\DataFilesToUpload\MarketReaserch34.jpeg
(Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.57)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-5', revision: 'b3a0d621cc'
System info: host: 'H21NGFFI13P0149', ip: '10.167.228.161', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

tried getting absulute path of the file and also tried direct passing the path in send keys but its not working.